# The Jupyter Notebook under localhost8888 not connecting

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

Good day ,

Whenever i use Jupyter notebooks, the notebook does not connect to the kernel and i can not run anything on the notebook.

Can anyone assist? The code is below.

```
      Kernel started: 99fb2fb7-ea73-4648-bb7b-87d70ac2cd25
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/usr/lib/**python3.5**/runpy.py", line **183**, in 
    run_module_as_mainmod_name, mod_spec, code = 
    _get_module_details(mod_name, _Error)
    File "/usr/lib/**python3.5**/runpy.py", line **142**, in 
    _get_module_details
    return _get_module_details(pkg_main_name, error)
    File "/usr/lib/**python3.5**/runpy.py", line **109**, in 
    _get_module_details__import__(pkg_name)
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/ipykernel/__init__.py", 
    line **2**, in <module> from .connect import *
    File "/usr/lib/**python3**/dist-packages/ipykernel/connect.py", 
    line **13**, in <module>from IPython.core.profiledir import 
    ProfileDir
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/IPython/__init__.py", line 
    49, in <module> from .terminal.embed import embed
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/IPython/terminal/embed.py", 
    line 17, in <module>from IPython.terminal.interactiveshell 
    import TerminalInteractiveShell 
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist- 
    packages/IPython/terminal/interactiveshell.py",line 19, in 
    <module>from prompt_toolkit.shortcuts import 
    create_prompt_application, 
    create_eventloop, create_prompt_layout, create_output
    ImportError: cannot import name 'create_prompt_application'
```

Comment: paste this `http://localhost:8888/?token=220ad9bb58b7c520245a0c716951ab70ad37cf8a267795e3` (the updated link after you launch the notebook) in your browser.

Comment: More specifically from @ReblochonMasque comment, you need to include the token when logging in remotely.  It literally tells you that with the lines: `copy and paste one of these URLs: http://localhost:8888?token=220ad9bb58b7c520245a0c716951ab70ad37cf8a267795e3`.  Each time you start the server, you will need to get the token to add to the url for login

Comment: Hi @Reblochon Masque , i have edited my original post to be as simple as possible and only included the parts of code (that appear in my terminal), that i believe are relevant to solving this mysterios case of python flu. Thank you for your previous assist, I did take your advice to copy and paste the links in the browser, and yet the problem persists, are you able to assist further?

Comment: Hi @James , I have edited my original post to be as simple as possible and only included the parts of code (that appear in my terminal), that i believe are relevant to solving this mysterios case of python flu. Thank you for your previous assist, I did take your advice to copy and then paste the URL / link in the browser, and yet the problem persists. Are you able to assist further?

Comment: Maybe the prompt_toolkit submodule shortcuts does not provide create_prompt_application? On github at https://github.com/prompt-toolkit/python-prompt-toolkit/blob/master/prompt_toolkit/shortcuts/__init__.py  I do not see the symbol in the __init__.py file of that folder. Are the versions of the local (conda?) install matching?

Comment: Show us the versions of the modules producing errors.